# JQuery for stackoverflow-like input textarea? Text->HTML

Tags: html, text, textarea, translation

I am looking for some textarea that help me to translate text to HTML. Like what stackoverflow input area does.

For example

`**bold**` is translated to `<span><b>bold</b></span>`

I am not sure what this is called. Thanks!

Comment: Stack Overflow uses Markdown as a markup language; you should be able to simply look up a JavaScript Markdown implementation and then update a preview area with the HTML whenever the text area changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stackoverflow is actually using WMD editor. Please refer to https://github.com/derobins/wmd

Comment: I think that http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/ is better than the editor of Stackoverfllow. It is easily implemented.